# How to read a regular text file?

Tags: c++, text

I am trying to write a program  will open a regular type file (binary or text/ASCII, read every byte in the file and write both the ASCII hex value for that byte as well as it’s printable (human-readable) character (characters, digits, symbols) to standard output. I am now just trying to let the user pick the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *file;
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]){
    int a;
    int modified = 1;//1 means unmodified, 0 means modified
    if(argc > 2){//writes to std error output
        return 25;
     }
    if(argc == 2){// if there is 1 argument open it and read it
        file = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
        if(file == NULL){//cant open file. return error code 15
            fprintf(stderr, "cant opent file %s \nerror code 15 \n", argv[1]);
            return 15;
        }
        a = getc(file);
    }else// get characters from stdin if no arguments
        a = getchar();


    char *buffer = malloc(200);
    int j = 0;// buffer index helper

    while( a != EOF){//reads character by character until EOF
              if(j  > 200){
                    j =0;
              //      fprintf(stderr,"error error, buffer overflow. \n error code 35 \n"); // send error to stderrl
              //      return 35;
                }
```

I am getting errors though:

`` error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `char*'
xsd.cpp:30: error: expected `}' at end of input
xsd.cpp:30: error: expected `}' at end of input ``

Comment: Are you missing a couple of } } at the end of the code or you just did not paste everything?

Comment: I usually suggest fixing the first error message first.  But in this case, leaving off closing braces is an error that is so simple it should be fixed even before posting the code.

Comment: Aren't those errors clear enough? Just read them, and handle them one after the other.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about actually reading.

Answer (score 3):

The major problem is that you write C in a C++ program. C and C++ are similar, due to C++ inheriting from C, but they are ultimately different languages. For example, C++ have a harder and tougher type system, so you can't e.g. have implicit cast from `void *` to other pointer types like you can in C. In C++ you have to cast `void *` to the correct pointer, like e.g.

```
char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(malloc(200));
```

Even better would be to not write C code in C++, and use the C++ functionality like [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)/[`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete), the [C++ input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), and classes like [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings, etc.

---

Then there's of course the problem of you not having enough closing braces `}` at the end of the program. Did you not copy-paste all of the program?

Comment: Obviously he C&P all his program: His compiler-errors prove it.

Comment: Yea I must of forgotten the }. jesus.. last time Im posting here. Also I needed to cast on char.. thanx for nothing.